# How to format time in JavaScript, without a framework

Tags: javascript

In input, I have a number of seconds.
In output, I want minutes and seconds, on two digits, separated by `:`

e.g.

- 1  -> 00:01
- 72 -> 01:12

I come up with the following code :

```
formatTime: function(nbSeconds) {
  var min = Math.ceil(nbSeconds/60);
  var sec = nbSeconds % 60;
  var formattedMin = min.toLocaleString('fr-FR', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 });
  var formattedSec = sec.toLocaleString('fr-FR', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 });
  return formattedMin + ":" + formattedSec;
},
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Passing 1 returned me `01:01`, use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.ceil` to get minutes, is that **better**?

Comment: try this  `var formatTime = function(ticks) {
    var hh = Math.floor( ticks / 3600);
    var mm = Math.floor( (ticks % 3600) / 60);
    var ss = (ticks % 3600) % 60;
    return hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    };`

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: Looks like a good fit for Code Review, though I wouldn't say our requirements are stricter, just different ^^

Comment: Check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33054094/4365315. If you have any problem, let me know